# Keep at least two numbers in list

Tags: r, list

I have a data test

```
test <- structure(list(V1 = c(1, NA, 4, NA), V2 = c(3, NA, 5, NA), V3 = c(NA,6, NA, NA), V4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), V5 = c(88,88, NA, NA)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"))
```

I remove `NA` using

```
test_1 <- lapply(test, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])

test_1
$V1
[1] 1 4
$V2
[1] 3 5
$V3
[1] 6
$V4
numeric(0)
$V5
[1] 88 88
```

`test_1$V3` and `test_1$V4` has only 1 or 0 numbers, and I want to keep at least two numbers in each list, so my expect is

```
 test_1
$V1
[1] 1 4
$V2
[1] 3 5
$V3
[1] 6  0
$V4
[1] 0  0
$V5
[1] 88 88
```

I just want to fill them with "0"

How to resolve this?

Comment: What if there are more than two non-NA elements in the list? You need to keep them , right?

Comment: Thanks for your comment,I will keep it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there can be more than two non-NA elements in the list. One way is

```
lapply(test, function(x) {
     x1 <- x[!is.na(x)]
     if(length(x1) < 2)
       c(x1, rep(0, 2 - length(x1)))
     else
       x1
})

#$V1
#[1] 1 4

#$V2
#[1] 3 5

#$V3
#[1] 6 0

#$V4
#[1] 0 0

#$V5
#[1] 88 88
```

Testing it on more than two non-NA list

```
test <- structure(list(V1 = c(1, NA, 4, NA, 5), V2 = c(3, NA, 5, NA), 
 V3 = c(NA,6, NA, NA), V4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_),
 V5 = c(88,88, NA, NA)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5")) 


#$V1
#[1] 1 4 5

#$V2
#[1] 3 5

#$V3
#[1] 6 0

#$V4
#[1] 0 0

#$V5
#[1] 88 88
```

---

As @thelatemail commented we can avoid the `if` check by using `max`

```
lapply(test, function(x) {
  x1 <- na.omit(x) #OR x[!is.na(x)]
  c(x1, rep(0, max(0,2-length(x1)))) 
})
```

This would append 0's only if the `length` of `x1` is less than 2.

Comment: Variation - `lapply(test, function(x) {o <- na.omit(x); c(o, rep(0, max(0,2-length(o)))) } )`

Comment: what different between na.omit(x) and x[!is.na(x)], thanks

Comment: @Pan it is different way of doing same thing.

Comment: which will be more efficient?

Comment: @Pan I am not completely sure but I think `na.omit` should be better.

Comment: @RonakShah - `x[!is.na(x)]` should be relatively faster as it doesn't save the attributes of which cases are missing.

Comment: @thelatemail is that so? I thought `x[!is.na(x)]` should be less efficient as we are getting first logical values using `is.na` and then we subset them.

Comment: @RonakShah - try it yourself - `x <- sample(c(1:3,NA), 5e6, replace=TRUE); system.time(na.omit(x)); system.time(x[!is.na(x)])`

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you fix it from the start, i.e. when you remove NA, where you can subset each vector by `1:n` with `n` being the number of elements you want to keep, this will result in NA if the length of vector is less than `n`, then you can replace `NA` with `0`:

```
test_1 <- lapply(test, function(x) { x1 <- x[!is.na(x)][1:2]; replace(x1, is.na(x1), 0) })

test_1
#$V1
#[1] 1 4

#$V2
#[1] 3 5

#$V3
#[1] 6 0

#$V4
#[1] 0 0

#$V5
#[1] 88 88
```

Comment: This would not work if there are more than 2 non-NA elements in a list.

Comment: @RonakShah Not quite sure. Since OP is trying to fill the vector with zeros, he possibly wants all vectors having same length as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.....

```
 test <- structure(list(V1 = c(1, NA, 4, NA), V2 = c(3, NA, 5, NA), 
                           V3 = c(NA,6, NA, NA),
                           V4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_),
                           V5 = c(88,88, NA, NA)), 
                           .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"))
    test_1 <- lapply(test, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])  ## Removed NA

    l <- length(test_1$V1)  # Taking length vectors required in a list
    df_NA <-  lapply(test_1, `length<-`, l)  ## Add NA to it
    rapply(df_NA, f=function(x) ifelse(is.na(x),0,x), how="replace" )  ## Replace the NA with zeros
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `purrr::map()` you could do

```
add_zeros <- function(x) {
  if(length(x) == 0) {
    x <- c(0, 0)
  } else if (length(x) == 1) {
    x <- c(x, 0)
  } else {
    x <- x
  }
}

test_1 %>% map(add_zeros)
```

Output:

```
$V1
[1] 1 4

$V2
[1] 3 5

$V3
[1] 6 0

$V4
[1] 0 0

$V5
[1] 88 88
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 lapply(test,function(x){y=x[!is.na(x)];if(length(y)<2)length(y)=2;y[is.na(y)]=0;y})
```

This also works without necessarily appending zerros.

```
 $V1
 [1] 1 4

 $V2
 [1] 3 5

 $V3
 [1] 6 0

 $V4
 [1] 0 0

 $V5
 [1] 88 88
```